# Hotend question posted as a answer

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[This answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/anet-a8-reading-739c-from-the-extruder-thermistor#answer-6143), from a new user, to the question, [Anet A8 reading 739°C from the extruder thermistor!](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/anet-a8-reading-739c-from-the-extruder-thermistor), quite clearly should have been posted as a question and referred back to the OPs question. The answer appears to have been provided by [Toonis, in a comment](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/anet-a8-reading-739c-from-the-extruder-thermistor#comment9139_6143).

Any idea as to how an answer can be converted to question, and then have the comment converted to an answer - without having to resort to the poster of the answer delete the answer and have them re-post it as a question, and then get Toonis to submit an answer?

Obviously, mods do not have a [big magic button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19288/how-to-stop-the-question-as-an-answer-problem#answer-19289) to do this automatically... and it would seem that [we have to delete it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25752/official-policy-on-questions-posted-as-answers#answer-25760), and ask the new user to post a *new* question. See also [Is it acceptable to post questions to the OP as an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68529/is-it-acceptable-to-post-questions-to-the-op-as-an-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way to go would be to migrate the answer (and its comments) to comments of the question.

As for Toonis' answer in the comment. I don't think that there is a way to create an answer for someone else. Functionality like that could be abused to achieve higher reputation. It's up to Toonis to create his/her own answer.

However, it is seen site-wide where users will create an answer attributing to the comment of another user. I think it is unspoken law that you remove your answer if the user ever creates their own answer. Ultimately, there are some users that just don't care about the reputation, so they would prefer to use the comments instead.

So, don't be afraid to create your own answer off of someone else's comments. Having explicit answers in the system will only make our site stronger.

Hit me up on [The Heat Element](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49795/the-heat-element) chatroom (specifically for 3D Printing Mods) and I can walk you through these steps.

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you mean. First, convert the answer and comments to comments of the original question, and then hope that the new user reposts the question. Then wait a while for Tonnis to submit an answer (and/or submit my own answer and delete when Tonnis submits the answer). Alternatively, we could just repost the question and answer (from Tonnis's comment) and mark both as a Community Wiki - just thought of the latter idea - but still do the convert to comments anyway. Regardless, *either way*, the convert to comments must be done first. Got it! :-)